# How to change these hard-coded cell references to dynamic references?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this spreadsheet:

[image]

and I have the following formula, which gets me exactly the results I need:

[image]

The problem I have is with the cell references being hard coded.  I need it all to be dynamic, because the information I'm targeting is based on the date. Today I need the information in rows 23-28. tomorrow it could be rows 5-10 or rows 30-40.

How can I look through the entire column A to find today's date, and then display only the rows of information pertaining to that date? I can do it with hard-coded row numbers, but I can't figure out how to do this with dynamic row numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula (it's a regular formula, no need for array entry):

```
=IF(ROW(A1)-1>=IFERROR(MATCH("*day",INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"m/dd")&"*",$A:$A,0)+1):$A$65000,0),IFERROR(MATCH(REPT("z",255),INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"m/dd")&"*",$A:$A,0)+1):$A$65000)+1,MATCH(2^999,INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"m/dd")&"*",$A:$A,0)+1):$A$65000)+1)),"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"m/dd")&"*",$A:$A,0)+ROW(A1)-1))
```

Then copy over and down to get all of your data.  Format the cells containing the formula with this custom format code: `General;General;;@` so that returns that should be blank are blank instead of 0s.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I'll have to break it down to understand what is happening there, but it works like a charm.

Comment: this is breaking down as the we're turning over a new month. I'm getting results for today (5/31) but Excel is returning #N/A for tomorrow (6/1) (TODAY()+1). I think that means it can't find 6/1, but I don't understand that. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @JustinWhite Ah, I see.  You'll need to update all instances of `"m/dd"` to instead be: `"m/d"` and then it will find 6/1 instead of looking for 6/01

Comment: I should have caught that. Thank you!

Comment: I've run into another problem with this. I've worked on it, but cannot figure it out. In my post, in the photo there is a line with the date 5/25, and then the next date is 5/28. That's breaking my results now. The current situation is that today is 6/1. There's nothing on the schedule until 6/4, so it's giving me results for 6/20. How can I tell it to look for the NEXT date instead of `TODAY()+1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the row references first as helpers and then change your current formula using `INDIRECT`

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A" & $K$19):INDIRECT("A" & $K$20)...
```

Where `K19` and `K20` are the cells where you have the formula which finds you the row number of today and not tomorrow.

You could put the formula to find the row numbers in instead of the reference like

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A" & FormulaFirstToday):INDIRECT("A" & FormulaLastToday)...
```